# When I publish my ASP.NET site in RELEASE mode, will tracing still work?

Tags: asp.net, publish, trace

When I publish my ASP.NET site in RELEASE mode, and set compilation debug="false", will my ASP.NET and System.Diagnostics Tracing still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that tracing is set separately from debugging in the configuration, so yes, if properly configured.

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware that tracing completely breaks any msajax stuff you have going on

Comment: True, I noticed it causes problems when enabling PageOutput. However, if I rather output to a standard trace listener all seems fine.